# Automated response download (json) Postman

Tags: json, api, automation, request, postman

Is it possible to create a Collection in Postman that executes a few hundred requests to an API and download all responses in json?

If it is possible, how to do that?

If it is not possible, what available tools do we have ? (free and open source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Newman as a library](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#using-newman-as-a-library) and the NodeJS [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module to do this:

```
const newman = require('newman'),
      fs = require('fs');

newman.run({
  collection: '<Collection File Or Link>'
}).on('request', (err, args) => {
  fs.writeFile(`./${args.item.name}.json`, args.response.stream, (err) => {
    if (err) { 
        console.error(err); 
    }
  });
});
```

This will run all the results in your Collection and then save each of the responses to a JSON file. The `filename` will be the name of the request.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks !! It is what I was looking for.